# cannot start swing timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm trying to make a Swing Timer that is executes when I press a button but never starts.
My code is:

```
public class prueba extends JFrame {
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    private JPanel contentPane;
    Timer timero;
        ........

public prueba() {
         ..........
        timero  = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              System.out.println("otra vez....uauuauauaua");
            }
          });
        btnIniciar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                  timero.start();
                                  ...............
```

Could you help me please?
Thanks and sorry for my english!

When I do these I have an error:

```
public class prueba extends JFrame {
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    private JPanel contentPane;
    Timer timero;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                prueba frame = new prueba();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public prueba() {




    final WebManager web = new WebManager("user","pass","http://www.spanishtracker.com/login.php");
    //web.EnableDebug();
    web.doLogin();
    web.getCookies;
        .....
    contentPane.add(txtSalida, gbc_txtSalida);

    timero.start();
```

it gives me an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at prueba.<init>(prueba.java:216)
    at prueba$1.run(prueba.java:56)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)

These lines are:
216         timero.start();
56      prueba frame = new prueba();
```

Comment: The code you posted looks good. Are you certain that `btnIniciar` is the button which is added in your UI ? You could use a debugger to verify this, or add a `System.out` call in the `ActionListener` of that button

Comment: Thanks. Yes I add a system.out and I verify that it goes in button but doesnt goes to the listener of the timer :-(

Comment: can you post your whole code ?

Comment: mmmmm. If I put the command in the beginning of the method prueba it gives me an error:

Comment: I've edited the main question. Thanks

Comment: post complete code. You are sure you initialized timero?

Comment: I initialice with: `     timero  = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           System.out.println("otra vez....uauuauauaua");
         }
       });`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have another `Timer` named `timero` that [*shadows*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2271186/230513) the one on which you call `.start()`. For reference, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513) shows how to start and stop a timer, and this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5529043/230513) shows how to expose a `start()` method that *forwards* to an enclosed timer. The latter is useful to avoid starting the timer prematurely, before the constructor concludes.